# cat command in unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cat

I have 2 lines of code

1) With the following code:

```
for i in `ls *.properties`; do cat $i; done
```

I get the error:

```
cat: file_name.properties: No such file or directory.
```

2) On the other hand:

```
for i in *.properties; do cat $i; done
```

Works fine!

I thought both were the same. Can someone help me understand the difference between the two? Using bash shell.

Comment: does your filename contain a space?

Comment: No it does not. Names are separated by underscores.

Comment: Please show an *actual* example. It doesn't have to be your real file names if you don't want to share, but something that demonstrates the problem you're seeing would be helpful.

Comment: The bare glob is correct anyway. You should never do `for i in \`ls\``. It might also be helpful to do `if [[ -f $i ]]; then cat "$i"; fi` to make sure you're only getting files and not directories. Note also that the variable should be quoted as I have done.

Comment: take look on this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) search cat

Comment: @khaled_webdev: That brings up lots of things, some incorrect. Can you be more specific what to search for on that page?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: see 'tdurden' comment (Command line while loop) , if it's wrong forget it

Comment: @khaled_webdev: `while read a ; do mv "$a" "$a.new" ; done < asdf`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does the following command print?

```
cat -v <<< `ls *.properties`
```

I guess the problem is, that `ls` is a strange alias, e.g. something like

```
ls='ls --color'
```

**Edit:** I have seen this before. The alias should be: `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`

Comment: Thank you nosid. There was an alias exactly as you mentioned. Appreciate it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Or even shorter: `alias ls`

Comment: I got the same issue also. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is a directory which matches `*.properties`. Then `ls` will output the files in this directory without the directory name. Then the `cat` will not find the given filename.

So please check, whether `file_name.properties` is in the actual directory or in some subdirectory.

**EDIT**

To reproduce the problem you can try this:

```
# cd /tmp
# mkdir foo.properties
# touch foo.properties/file_name.properties
# for i in `ls *.properties`; do cat $i; done
cat: file_name.properties: No such file or directory
```

Comment: nice idea but in this case he would first see `cat: directoryname:: No such file or directory.` (note the double colon)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath you won't, because `ls dir` will output the _contents_ of the directory but not the text `dir` itself. Hence `cat` wont see this name and cannot produce the output you proposed.

Comment: @Karoly, neat, I've never noticed that before; `cat: rc0.d:: No such file or directory`. :)

Comment: @A.H.: that's because you did the `ls` with only one argument.